# gulp-sourcemap file extension issue

Tags: css, less, gulp

Trying to create a gulp file that picks up our LESS files and generates the appropriate .css, .min.css, and .css.map files.  Close, but sourcemaps is writing the map to a file with the extension .css.min.css.

```
/// <vs BeforeBuild='less' SolutionOpened='less' />
/// <binding BeforeBuild='less' ProjectOpened='less' />
var gulp = require('gulp');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var pleeease = require('gulp-pleeease');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var mqpacker = require('css-mqpacker');
var csswring = require('csswring');
var postcss = require('gulp-postcss');

var processors = [
        autoprefixer({ browsers: ["IE >= 9, firefox > 10, last 2 Chrome versions, last 2 safari versions, last 2 ios versions"] }),
        mqpacker
];
gulp.task('less', function () {
    gulp.src('./itims/Content/*.less', { base: './itims/content'})
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(postcss(processors))
        .pipe(rename({
            extname: '.css'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./itims/content'))
        .pipe(minifycss())
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(rename({
            suffix: '.min',
            extname: '.css'
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./itims/content'));
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you might guess, your problem comes from the `rename` that is after the `sourcemaps.write`. You want to rename only `*.css` files, hence the following solution should do the trick :

1. **Add `gulp-if` to your dependencies if not already present**

   ```
   var if = require('gulp-if');
   ```
2. **Rewrite your task as follows :**

   ```
   gulp.src('./itims/content/*.less', {base: './itims/content'})
       .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
       .pipe(less())
       .pipe(postcss(processors))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./itims/content'))
       .pipe(minifycss())
       .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
       .pipe(if('*.css', rename({extname: '.min.css'}))
       .pipe(gulp.dest('./itims/content'));
   ```

Notes:

- I removed your first rename as the less plugin already handles the renaming of `*.less` to `*.css`
- Beware of the case in the path names. You mixed `'./itims/Content'` and `'./itims/content'`.

Comment: Can I assume that sourcemaps.write then isn't actually writing the file at that point, but sending a virtual file through the pipeline?

Comment: Indeed, that's why you need a `gulp.dest(...)` after that.

Comment: I couldn't get it working with '*.css'' instead I used '**/ *.css' Without space before the last asterisk.